# Detecting and flagging Scheduled Tasks that have run incorrectly

Tags: email, scheduled-task

I have a number of scheduled tasks that run on various Windows servers. They are mostly custom console applications which we have written.
Currently, when the app has finished running, we send out an email to our operators to confirm that it is complete.

This works fine in most cases, but the problem we've been having is if a scheduled task *doesn't* run for some reason. Currently, we've given them a list of emails that they ought to be expecting each morning, and they are expected to notice if one doesn't arrive.

I'd like to make this a more automated process.

So... How is best to go about notifying the operators if a task hasn't run?
What about if the console app is started, but doesn't complete for some reason (crash, or whatever)?

Is email the way to go? Should we be sending out our notifications some other way?
Do I need some more beefy scheduling software?

Apologies if this is well trodden ground... I'm a Dev, rather than an Admin, so this is outside my competence!

Comment: Is this windows and do these unrun tasks show as failed in the tasks scheduler?

Comment: Hi Tony... The Servers are all Windows 2003. I've edited the question to make it a bit clearer. Basically, the issue is if the scheduled task fires, but then the console app crashes before it gets to any code that can send emails. I think in this case, the scheduled task shows as having run?

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to find a reliable way to see why scheduled tasks haven't run.  It "should" throw errors into the event log but I've found that it doesn't always.  You are probably going to be better off (i.e.: more reliable) building some error handling into your app.